# check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

```
<?php include 'config.php';


    $user_id = 1;
    $postid = 9;
    $content = "sdfsdfsdfsdf";
    $date = '24';
    $category_id = 4;



$result = $db->query("INSERT INTO post_items(`post_id`,`content`,`date`,`user_id`,`category_id`) 
    VALUES ('".$postid.", '".$content."', '".$date."', '".$user_id."', '".$category_id."')");

if($result) { 
    echo "hey";
}else{
    echo $db->error;
}



?>
```

Please help, I've tried 3-4 hours but no luck.. I'm very sure all my column is correct, I'm so confused how to use sql syntax now, because I went to MySQL visual editor, it gave me different sql query for insert.

Comment: Please do not re-post questions.

Comment: Instead of passing the string straight into `$db->query()`, store it into a variable, from which you can `echo $query_var;` in order to see what it contains and how to debug it.

Comment: And that's not the whole MySQL error. What does it say after that? It should point to an error character _check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the correct syntax to use near_...

Answer (score 2):

Missing the ' after $postId

```
VALUES ('".$postid.", '".$content."', '".$date."', '".$user
--------------------^
```

Answer (score 1):

```
VALUES ('".$postid.", '".$con ...
        ^           ^^^
```

It appears that you have missed a single quote. It should be:

```
VALUES ('".$postid."', '".$con ...
                    ^
                 add this
```

This is yet another good reason (beyond the already excellent one of avoiding SQL injection attacks) that you should prefer parameterised queries. They're much more readable hence easier to debug.

Comment: Lol, don't confuse the poor guy ;)